# Deleting stop-words and punctuation signs

Tags: python, text-analysis, stop-words

I parse information from a news website. Each news is a dictionary that is stored inside translated_news variable. Each news has its title, url and country.
Then I try to iterate over each news title and delete stop-words and punctuation signs. I've written this code:

```
for new in translated_news:
    tk = tokenize(new['title'])
    # delete punctuation signs & stop-words
    for t in tk:
        if (t in punkts) or (t+'\n' in stops):
            tk.remove(t)
tokens.append(tk)
```

Tokenize is a function that returns a list of tokens. Here's an example of the output:

```
['medium', ':', 'russian', 'athlete', 'will', 'be', 'admit', 'to', 'the', '2018', 'olympics', 'in', 'neutral', 'status']
```

Here's the same output, but with deleted stop-words and punctuation:

```
['medium', 'russian', 'athlete', 'be', 'admit', 'the', 'olympics', 'neutral', 'status']
```

The problem is: even though the words 'the' and 'be' are included in my stop-words list, they were not deleted from the news title. However, on other titles it sometimes works correctly:

`['wada', 'acknowledge', 'the', 'reliable', 'information', 'provide', 'to', 'rodchenkov']
['wada', 'acknowledge', 'reliable', 'information', 'provide', 'rodchenkov']`

Here 'the' was deleted from the title.
I don't understand what is wrong with the code and why sometimes the output is perfect and sometimes not.

Comment: Good post but missing `tk`! How does `tk` looks like? Try to `print(tk)` when it does fail.

Comment: tk is a list of words, I have shown it in the post (for example, ['medium', ':', 'russian', 'athlete', 'will', 'be', 'admit', 'to', 'the', '2018', 'olympics', 'in', 'neutral', 'status'])

Comment: Please post `stops` words in your question! Your code works perfectly fine. The answer's code does not work perfectly fine.

Comment: @ElisByberi the list of stop-words is so long that it will make my question unreadable. And I suppose the question is already resolved by the person below, so there's no need to discuss it anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to iterate on `tokenize(new['title'])` and use [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) to simplify the if statement:

```
import string

stops = ['will', 'be', 'to', 'the', 'in']

tk = ['medium', ':', 'russian', 'athlete', 'will', 'be', 'admit', 'to', 'the',
      '2018', 'olympics', 'in', 'neutral', 'status']

# delete punctuation signs & stop-words
tk = []
for t in tokenize(new['title']):
    # if not ((t in string.punctuation) or (t in stops)):
    if (t not in string.punctuation) and (t not in stops): # De Morgan's laws
        tk.append(t)
print(tk)
```

will print:

```
['medium', 'russian', 'athlete', 'admit', '2018', 'olympics', 'neutral', 'status']
```

You can get rid of new lines in stops words:

```
stops = ['will\n', 'be\n', 'to\n', 'the\n', 'in\n']
stops = [item.strip() for item in stops]
print(stops)
```

will print:

```
['will', 'be', 'to', 'the', 'in']
```

---

The solution suggested from *incanus86* does work:

```
tk = [x for x in tokenize(new['title']) if x not in stops and x not in string.punctuation]
```

but you won't be asking in SO if you knew about [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

---

> I don't understand what is wrong with the code and why sometimes the output is perfect and sometimes not.

While iterating on `tk` items you do miss `'be'` and `'the'` because you are removing `tk` items as seen in code:

```
import string

stops = ['will', 'be', 'to', 'the', 'in']

tk = [
    'medium',  # 0
    ':',  # 1
    'russian',  # 2
    'athlete',  # 3
    'will',  # 4
    'be',  # 5
    'admit',  # 6
    'to',  # 7
    'the',  # 8
    '2018',  # 9
    'olympics',  # 10
    'in',  # 11
    'neutral',  # 12
    'status'  # 13
]

# delete punctuation signs & stop-words
for t in tk:
    print(len(tk), t, tk.index(t))
    if (t in string.punctuation) or (t in stops):
        tk.remove(t)

print(tk)
```

will print:

```
(14, 'medium', 0)
(14, ':', 1)
(13, 'athlete', 2)
(13, 'will', 3)
(12, 'admit', 4)
(12, 'to', 5)
(11, '2018', 6)
(11, 'olympics', 7)
(11, 'in', 8)
(10, 'status', 9)
['medium', 'russian', 'athlete', 'be', 'admit', 'the', '2018', 'olympics', 'neutral', 'status']
```

You do miss **"russian"**, **"be"**, **"the"** and **"neutral"**.
Index of "athlete" is 2 and index of  "will" is 3 because you removed ":" from tk.
Index of "admit" is 4 and index if "to" is 5 because you removed "will" from tk.
Index of "2018" is 6, index of "olympics" is 7, index of "in" is 8 and index of "status" is 9.

**You MUST not change list while iterating on it!**

Answer (score 0):

Try getting rid of the newline character.

something like this

```
tk = [x for x in tokenize(new['title']) if x not in stops and x not in string.punctuation]
```

Comment: The thing is that stops is a list of words like ['a\n', 'about\n', 'all\n'], each word has '\n' at the end. I have tried getting rid of '\n' in each item of the list like with rstrip(), but it didn't work. However, thank you for the comment, I'll try it out

Comment: Your solution worked perfctly fine, but I still don't understand what was wrong with my code.